# Get the service IPs ports running under mesospehere dcos through program or command

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, mesosphere, dcos

I want to connect to Cassandra which is running as a service in Mesosphere DC/OS. Is there any programmatic way(any api exposed) to get the Cassandra port and ip details ?

From Command I can connect like below... same thing I want to do it programmatically may be with REST api... or Java client to connect to these services.

As per this doc https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-cassandra-service/blob/master/docs/connecting-clients.md

```
$ dcos cassandra --name=<service-name> connection

{
  "address": [
    "10.0.0.47:9042",
    "10.0.0.50:9042",
    "10.0.0.49:9042"
  ],
  "dns": [
     "node-0.cassandra.mesos:9042",
     "node-1.cassandra.mesos:9042",
     "node-2.cassandra.mesos:9042"
  ]
}
```

Note : The reason for doing this is every time cassandra IP and port changing. I have to manually adjust in my property file to get the latest details. If its through program its very easy to set the property with out manual interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the entries from the DNS section (shown below) they would not change even if the task relocated to another node

```
 "node-0.cassandra.mesos:9042",
 "node-1.cassandra.mesos:9042",
 "node-2.cassandra.mesos:9042"
```